# Covering space(s) of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^2$ minus one point

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I know that the covering space of  $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is $S^2$, and it is unique unless than isomorphism of covering spaces.
Now, $S^2$ minus one point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (by stereographic projection), and so $S^2$ minus two points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus one point, which is homotopically equivalent to $S^1$ (more specifically, $S^1$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus one point). Then, we have a surjective map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus one point to $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^2$ minus one point. 
Is it a covering map? And if yes, how can I see this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ok with knowing how to describe the map up to homotopy? If so, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle and $\mathbb{R}P^2\setminus\{p\}$ is also homotopy equivalent to a circle. If you factor the map $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}P^2\setminus\{p\}$ through these homotopy equivalences, we get the doubling map $S^1\to S^1$ which is a covering space.

That is, the deformation retractions $h_1$ and $h_2$,the surjection $s$ onto the punctured projective plane, and the doubling map on the circle fit into a commutative (up to homotopy) diagram:
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
   \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}    & \ra{s}       &    \mathbb{R}P^2\setminus\{p\}     \\
  \da{h_1}     &              &  \da{h_2}               \\
   S^1       & \ras{\times 2} &    S^1                        \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: There is something i'm missing. Why $\mathbb{R}P^2$ minus one point is homotopy equivalent to a circle?

Comment: Ok, the real projective plane minus one point is homeomorphic to the Möbius strip without boundary. But, why when you factor the map, you gets the doubling map?

Comment: @user84151 If you identify $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ with the sphere with it's north and south poles removed, then $s$ is just the usual quotient map induced by the antipodal relation of the sphere but restricted to the punctured subspace. The deformation retraction of the punctured plane to the circle can then be considered to be the deformation retraction of this double-punctured sphere onto its equator. The induced map on the equator of the antipodal quotient is the doubling map.

Comment: Ok!Thank you very much!:)

Comment: @DanRust, should it be $\mathbb{R}^2  \setminus \{0\}$ as the domain of $s$ in your commutative diagram above?